# Google play console crash error unable to understand

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, google-play-console

[image]

Code is written in React Native, and I am unable to understand the crash error.

[image]

crash error

Answer (score 0):

when errors occurred on a bundled React Native APK it's almost impossible to understand what really caused it as the transpiler changes variables and functions names.

One thing I would suggest you is adding an error tracker to your app such as Sentry or Crashlytics.

Another good practice is wrapping your code with `try` and `cacth`es, that way you can log your errors and prevent an App crash.